# Mac maverick binded to AD

Tags: active-directory, mac

I got a mac laptop binded to AD successfully. Logged in with a domain user and it created a mobile account. The user used it for a day then rebooted and find that they can't login anymore. I logged in fine with the local account. Then got them to try and SSH onto the mac and surprising it got them in.

I ran dscl on the mac and try to browse it. It shows the domain but when I go deeper it shows  DS Error: -14009 (eDSUnknownNodeName).

system.log shows

SecurityAgent[512]: User "xxx" does not have permission to log in to this machine
SecurityAgent[512]: Could not get the user record from OpenDirectory.

Only allows the user to ssh onto the machine but not via the login window!

edit: when I ssh onto the machine and id the domain account. It is showing all the info.

Comment: No idea what happened but even running kinit is fine. Rebinding it to AD didn't help so I just reimaged it.